# how to deploy an entire github repository to actively running ec2 instance?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

hello I'm trying to deploy the entire github repository to EC2 instance.

What I want to do is to deploy the entire branch (entire github repo) to EC2 instance.
The EC2 instance I'm trying to deploy the repo to is fully functioning webpage with its contents already. So I'm not trying to deploy a new app to a newly created EC2 instance but deploy entire branch of github repo to the already existing EC2.

I've tried CodeDeploy but I think only works for deploying revision made in the repository; it always requires committer ID from the repository which only deploys the code pulled from that specific committer ID.

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: There are many ways to do what you're talking about.  What's best for you will depend on a lot of things you aren't telling us, like just how your app is structured, how the repo you want to deploy relates to the running app, what your existing CICD pipeline looks like, how the branch you want to deploy compares to the one you already have on the instance, etc.  A simple answer, something we do all the time, is to check out the branch somewhere else and just do a `rsync` to the instance to update the files on it.

Comment: @CryptoFool thank you so much for pointing some criteria I need to look into! I just joined the project so I'm still little lost about most things and also I'm a total noob to whole aws devops; I think once I can find answers to your questions, I can guide myself to the right direction.